# QML javascript: "this" becomes undefined in class constructor under if(){...} if in arrow function

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

In QML javascript, when executing a pure-javascript class constructor, "this" becomes momentarily undefined in code under `if (cond) { ... }` but is otherwise valid as is should be.

This problem (seemingly) occurs only if the code is in the body of an anonymous arrow function.  JS arrow functions do not provide "this" or do anything with it, so the symbol `this` should refer to it's definition in the enclosing scope, i.e. the class constructor; and it is, *except* in `if (c) {...}` conditionals!

What can possibly explain this?

```
import QtQuick 2.14
Item {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    class Bugtest {
      constructor() {
        this.foo = 123;
        ((arg) => {
          print("BEFORE if: this="+this+", foo="+this.foo);
          if (true) {
            print("DURING if: this="+this); //undefined here only!!
          }
          print("AFTER  if: this="+this+", foo="+this.foo);
        })(42);
        print("At constructor exit: this="+this+", foo="+this.foo);
      }
    };

    var xyz = new Bugtest();
  }
}
```

Running the above with *qml* (or *qmlscene*) v6.2.1 or v5.15.2 produces:

```
qml: BEFORE if: this=[object Object], foo=123
qml: DURING if: this=undefined
qml: AFTER  if: this=[object Object], foo=123
qml: At constructor exit: this=[object Object], foo=123
```

Comment: That's a really interesting question. It sounds like it must be a bug. Did you try submitting a bug report?

Comment: Just now. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-98039

Answer (score 1):

This does seem like a QML bug where the scoping of the "this" binding is broken. While I can't explain why this would be, I found a workaround, where you explicitly `.bind(this)` before entering the function, which causes the contents of the `if` conditional to evaluate properly:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Item {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    class Bugtest {
      constructor() {
        this.foo = 123;
        ((arg) => {
          console.log("BEFORE if: this="+this+", foo="+this.foo);
          if (true) {
            console.log("DURING if: this="+this+", foo="+this.foo); // now works in QML and JSFiddle
          }
          console.log("AFTER  if: this="+this+", foo="+this.foo);
        }).bind(this)(42); // added explicit 'this' bind here
        console.log("At constructor exit: this="+this+", foo="+this.foo);
      }
    };

    var xyz = new Bugtest();
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not develop with QML, so I'll have to ask here: do you know if `.bind()` works here in the way that you can bind *any* object to it? Or could you go `.bind(null)` and have the context still be correct?

Comment: @GustvandeWal Interesting questions. I no longer have access to QML so I can't test what happens there. However, on JSFiddle, your latter idea is true. JS documentation indicates this is also the case: `.bind()` should have no effect on arrow functions. So it seems like `bind` having an effect on QML arrow functions is also a bug.